# How to choose dependency versions on Android Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library

so my question is simple, 
how can i choose my android support library versions ?? 
 - should i go for the highest or lowest one to prevent conflict ? and WHY ?

PS: logically i'll go for the highest version, but if someone who uses my library use an older functionality that is removed in the newer one,  he must upgrade and refactor his code.
also using the lowest version doesn't really make sense.

Thnx for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should i go for the highest or lowest one to prevent conflict ? and WHY ?

Since the only reason they introduce new levels are improvements (bug, performance, security and etc.) you should go with latest or close to latest.

> PS: logically i'll go for the highest version, but if someone who uses my library use an older functionality that is removed in the newer one, he must upgrade and refactor his code. also using the lowest version doesn't really make sense.

If all library developers were to think every single library user instead of general audience then all libraries should be implementing stone-age support libraries. Plus google won’t deprecate generally useful APIs, so you don’t have to worry about it.

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, 

just another question please : 
since the latest version of support library v4 require the same minimum Api level as android support library v7

does that mean that using . v4 became useless now ?

Comment: Actually, in Android docs (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7) in the second note, it states that "Note: This library depends on the v4 Support Library. ". So that means if you're using `v7` support library you're automatically dependent on the `v4` support library. When it comes calling "useless", I would rather say: The naming of libraries are useless (or obsolete) not the library itself. Because even if you convert to `AndroidX` you're still gonna use same features under another package. For example, `support.view` will be `androidx.view` and etc.

Comment: By the way, I can see that you don't want to convert to `AndroidX` yet. I would recommend you to do so in a year or so. Because if you don't, you'll be missing out quite a lot of features and improvements. But for a year or so, you're safe, I guess))

Answer (score 0):

Use AndroidX. Support libraries are deprecated

You can find last AndroidX versions [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions)

Comment: Users don't want to use AndroisX, this is due to large refractor they must do in their projects (Jetifer isn't perfect)
beside, i think a good library is a library where you have the most freedom available for the user. 

i don't know why i can't use androidx with support library in same time lol 
thnx